# How to keep my blitted image on screen once thy are created

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a simple tic tac toe game in which there is an image that I blit on a mouse up event...but due to the game loop, it disappears the very next moment. Here is the code...can anybody help me on how to keep it on-screen once it is blitted by the mouse..

```
toggle = True
# Game loop.
while True:
    box = 0
...
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if rect_1.collidepoint(pos):
                box = 1
                toggle = not toggle
...
   screen.fill((235, 235, 235))
       if box != 0:
           if (toggle):
               if (box == 1):
                   cross_rect = cross_minified.get_rect(center=rect_1.center)
                   screen.blit(cross_minified, cross_rect)
```

can anyone please suggest me a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the Solution Guys, I simply used a list and check if the value is appended or not and if appended I just blitted it to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Initailize box above the loop:

```
toggle = True
# Game loop.
box = 0
while True:
...
```

Comment: But then when we click on other boxes the value of x is changed from 1 to 2,34 etc and it disappers